# How to get random row from file in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I'm looking for way how to get random row from file in JMeter.
I would be appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure regarding groovy, maybe there is an easier way, but for instance you can do it with [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) using the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; //necessary import

List lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/your/file"));  // read file into lines array   
int random = new Random().nextInt(lines.size()); // get random line number
String randomLine = lines.get(random); // get random line

vars.put("randomLine", randomLine); // store the random line into ${randomLine} variable
```

- substitute `/path/to/your/file` with relative or absolute path to the file you want the random line from
- you will be able to access the random line as `${randomLine}` where required

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java APIs from Beanshell test elements in your JMeter test

N.B. The above code is valid groovy code as well

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using a bean shell controller. Here you will need to do bit of programming to achieve the desired behaviour.

There is an easy way to achieve the desired outcome.
Introduce a ransom timer into your thread group.
The timer will ensure the randomness of the threads.
Configure a CSV confit element to read data from a file.
Ensure the file is shared with all the threads.

Comment: Of course, I know that is possible but I expect sample code for do this

Answer (score 0):

you can get a random var

```
random__Random(1,9)
//syntax: __Random(start,end)
```

Then you can pull out

```
File fileInstance = new File("path/yourfile.txt");
readerInstance = new IndexedFileReader(fileInstance);
lines = readerInstance.readLines(randomIdx, randomIdx+1);
```

readLines takes a start and an end line number..

However if you are using anything other then very small files, with low iterations I really suggest you read the entire file into a buffer, and use the random var to pull lines from that

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Random CSV Data Set Config Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter) Jmeter plugin by Blazemeter. It has all the randomising a regualr user will want on top of the conventional JMeters CSV Data Set Config.